# Trouble implementing Swift Result<Success, Error> in API request

Tags: ios, swift

I am intentionally creating a user that already exists in MongoDB to display an error message to the user, such as "Please choose a different username" or "email already in use" but I am having trouble decoding the server's response.

My model is designed to handle the success(user/token) or error response(message)...

I am able to successfully decode the user object when an account is created on the backend...

What I am doing wrong? I feel like I should be using an enum for the error model somehow??

```
// POSTMAN RESPONSE WHEN USERNAME ALREADY TAKEN
{
    "success": false,
    "message": "Please choose a different username"
}

// XCODE ERROR MESSAGE 

//...Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data 
//instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

```
// DATA MODELS

struct UserResponse: Decodable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: ErrorResponse?
    var user: User?
    var token: String?
}

struct ErrorResponse: Decodable, Error {
    let message: String
}
```

```
class LoginService {
    
     static func createAccount(username: String, email: String, password: String, 
completion: @escaping(Result <UserResponse, Error>) -> Void) {
     
        let user = UserSignup(username: username, email: email, password: password)
        
        // Create URL code
       
        do {
            let encoder = JSONEncoder()
            urlRequest.httpBody = try encoder.encode(user)
           
            let dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: urlRequest) { data, response, error in
               
                if let error = error {
                    completion(.failure(error))
                    return
                }
                guard let jsonData = data else { return }
    
                do {
                    let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserResponse.self, from: jsonData)
                    switch responseObject.success {
                    case true:
                        completion(.success(responseObject))
                    case false:
                        // not working
                        guard let errorMessage = responseObject.message else {
                          return
                        }
                        completion(.failure(errorMessage))
                    }
                } catch {
                    print(error)
                }
            }
            dataTask.resume()
        } catch {
            // handle error
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error says `message` is a string so declare it as `String`

```
struct UserResponse: Decodable {
    let success: Bool
    let message: String?
    var user: User?
    var token: String?
}
```

> I feel like I should be using an enum for the error model somehow

That's a good idea to get rid of the optionals. The enum first decodes `status` and depending on the value it decodes the `user` and `token` on success and the error `message` on failure

```
struct UserResponse {
    let user: User
    let token: String
}

enum Response : Decodable {
    case success(UserResponse)
    case failure(String)
    
    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey { case success, message, user, token }
    
    init(from decoder : Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let success = try container.decode(Bool.self, forKey: .success)
        if success {
            let user = try container.decode(User.self, forKey: .user)
            let token = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .token)
            self = .success(UserResponse(user: user, token: token))
        } else {
            let message = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .message)
            self = .failure(message)
        }
    }
}
```

Then you can replace

```
   let responseObject = try JSONDecoder().decode(UserResponse.self, from: jsonData)
    switch responseObject.success {
    case true:
        completion(.success(responseObject))
    case false:
        // not working
        guard let errorMessage = responseObject.message else {
          return
        }
        completion(.failure(errorMessage))
    }
```

with

```
   let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: jsonData)
    switch response {
    case .success(let responseObject):
        completion(.success(responseObject))
    case .failure(let errorMessage)
        completion(.failure(errorMessage))
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much vadian :)

Comment: very nice solution :)

Comment: You have to declare an enum conforming to `Error` for example `enum UserError : Error { case userExists(String) }` then you can write `completion(.failure(UserError.userExists(errorMessage)))`